# Angular Universal with Abp Framwork

Tags: angular, typescript, seo, angular-universal, abp

#### Angular Universal with Abp Framwork

I try to add angular universal to project abp angular

I add this command
ng add @nguniversal/express-engine

after that all files were create and add server.ts file automatically
after that the project build succussed by this command  build:ssr
when run this command serve:ssr
some problems appear
the first is localStorage is not defined

I fixed it  by update app.module.ts with this code
`

```
 export class AuthModule {

  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders<AbpOAuthModule> {

    return {

      ngModule: AuthModule,

      providers: [
        { provide: OAuthStorage, useFactory: storageFactory },
        { provide: "windowObject", useValue: window}
      ]

    };

  }

} 

export function storageFactory() : OAuthStorage {
  return localStorage
}
```

`

and update the NgModule on the same file

```
@NgModule({

 declarations: [AppComponent],

 imports: [

   BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'serverApp' }),

   OAuthModule.forRoot(),
```

after that a problem appear
./node_modules/@volo/ngx-lepton-x.core/fesm2020/volo-ngx-lepton-x.core.mjs:1235
return { provide: WINDOW, useValue: windowObj || window };
and I do not know how to fix it
I try to update the server.ts file
I add this

```
   const domino = require('domino');
  const win = domino.createWindow(indexHtml);
  // mock
  global['window'] = win;
  global['document'] = win.document;
  global['navigator'] = win.navigator;
```

to define the window on the server side but it does not work
I guess there is some thing run in the abp library calling the localstorage and window
before the server.ts
After that I try to do some steps from this  article
https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/4711
after I install jsdom , global-jsdom
some new errors appear
./node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/utils.js:139:2-27 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'canvas' in \AngularUniversal\angular\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom
After I install the Canvas a new error appear
./node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node:1:2 - Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
So, if abp angular support angular universal?
If support what are the steps to do it for build succussed and run with out problems

- Your **ABP Framework version** 7.0.1.
- Your **Angular Framework version** 15.*
- Your **User Interface** type (Angular) if the issue is related to a specific UI